# What are all the most common method/variable/class names that you use?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Most common method/variable/class names that you use often and that explain you intent clearly and precisely.Is there any pattern you follow to figure that out.

Comment: ... community wiki demand bombs away in 4..3..2...

Comment: Ken O. Burtch wrote a script and scanned some software projects:
http://www.pegasoft.ca/coder/coder_july_2014.html

Answer (score 2):

`int i = 0;`

I guess.

Comment: that's part of a `for` loop i hope ;)

Answer (score 1):

`object sender, EventArgs e`

Answer (score 0):

It's not common names, but common patterns of names I think you need

So I try to make the variables mean something

```
successfulTransmissionCount

widgetUnitPrice

unusedSessionTimeout
```

But then on occasions, where there is scope for ambiguity I may use a "units" suffix. If I'm dealing with two existing APIs one that works in seconds and one that works in milliseconds it really helps my eyes to be reminded of the units

```
 long unusedSessionTimeoutMillis
```

(Yes there are alternatives to using raw primitive types that may give the same effect)